# Format toLocaleDateString date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, date

I want to format my localized date in `dd MMM, yyyy` format.

```
Ex. 
In en => 30 Jan, 2019
In fr => 30 janv., 2019
In zh-CN => 30日 1月, 2019年
and so on.
```

I'm using javascript's `toLocaleDateString`() method. Following is my code:

```
var dateObj = new Date(parseInt(timestamp));
var date = dateObj.toLocaleDateString(window.userLang, { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric' });
```

Well, it's working fine but not in the format which I want.

Ex:
For English its translating like Jan 30, 2019 based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

In Angular, we can achieve this by passing desired format to datePipe.transform() like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dateFormatPipe',
})
export class dateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string) {            
        let datePipe = new DatePipe((<any>window).userLang);
        value = datePipe.transform(value, 'dd MMM, yyyy'); 
        return value;
    }
}
```

It'll print the output as I mentioned earlier:

```
In en => 30 Jan, 2019
In fr => 30 janv., 2019
In zh-CN => 30日 1月, 2019年
```

Is there any such way in javascript/jquery to achieve this?

Comment: `toLocaleDateString` was introduced so that you do *not* format dates in arbitrary and unusual formats. People expect the date format which is most common in their respective locale, not the format that you think is best.

Comment: @str: right but as you can see in my post in angular we can do this without disturbing its locale

Comment: @str—I beg to differ, people expect dates in unambiguous formats in their native language, they really don’t care too much about “locale” formats. I consider the formats produced by *toLocaleString* to be arbitrary.

Comment: @RobG: Yes exactly and that's what the requirement I got but unfortunately I've only JS/JQuery to implement this

Comment: @Sky—I think the intention of *toLoacleString* is well meaning, but it seeks to standardise something that doesn’t lend itself well to standardisation. There a plenty of date format standards already.

Comment: @RobG: Yes I agree but that's how the requirement is

Comment: @Sky What do you mean by "without disturbing its locale"? "dd MMM, yyyy" is a very uncommon format in my locale. Requirements can (and should) always be challenged.

Comment: @RobG It is probably a matter of opinion. I just don't think that enforcing a single format (which might be totally uncommon) to everybody is better than a locale-specific date format (which ideally is the most-used format in that specific locale).

Comment: @str—sure, but "locale" is defined by a language code, which, while based on how a language is spoken in a particular region, doesn't define a user's locale, which is more likely how they expect dates to be presented. Also, many places use multiple formats, so nailing it down to one particular format is contentious anyway. It's a vexed issue that has no concrete answer, I just prefer to go with an unambiguous format, at least that way even if it's not the user's preferred format, at least they won't misconstrue it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to force a particular format for every language, *toLocaleString* can help with the language part for each component, then put the components in the order you want, e.g.

```js
function formatDate(date, langCode) {
  var day = date.toLocaleString(langCode, {day: '2-digit'});   // DD
  var month = date.toLocaleString(langCode, {month: 'short'}); // MMM
  var year = date.toLocaleString(langCode, {year: 'numeric'}); // YYYY
  return `${day} ${month}, ${year}`;
}

// Examples
var d = new Date();
['en',    // English
 'ja',    // Japanese
 'zh-CN', // Chinese, simplified
 'fr',    // French
 'ar'     // Arabic
].forEach(lang => console.log(formatDate(d, lang)));

// Attempt to use prefered browser language
console.log(formatDate(d, navigator.languages));
```

However, that may not suit every case and you still need to determine which language to use. You might try [*navigator.languages*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages), it's experimental but reasonably well supported. However, I don't trust it as I think users rarely set it to the values they want and just accept the default. However, if someone is using a browser hopefully they'll understand a date in the browser's default language, provided it's in an unambiguous format (such as DD MMM, YYYY).

There are lots of [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+detect+user+language) for determining the language, and likely there are languages that aren't supported by certain implementations.

PS. There are many different token sets for date formatting, I've used the ones for [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), there are many others.