# Custom delimiter in a formatted date with Date::toLocaleDateString()

Tags: javascript

I'm using toLocaleDatestring to give format to my date. Te current function I'm using is the following:

```
var oDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { year: "numeric", day: "2-digit", month: "short"})
```

And it actualy works, it's giving me "Jun 09, 2023" as result

My question is, is there any way to give to it a different format. I'm I want it like "Jun/09/2023"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format toLocaleDateString date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438906/format-tolocaledatestring-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Consider using "moment" npm package

Comment: @ArjisChakraborty moment is very close to being deprecated; it's in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important part here that `toLocaleDateString()` is a wrapper to `Intl.DateTimeFormat`. It creates an instance of `Intl.DateTimeFormat` every time and that's very expensive operation. So if you plan to use your format in many places like processing lists you should create only one instance of `Intl.DateTimeFormat` and reuse it.

You could use RegExp to tweak your formatted date or get separate parts with `formatToParts()` and join them with either `reduce` or `filter/map/join`.

But I recommend to format your dates manually as it's the fastest. If you have many dates to format like from backend data (a list of items with several dates per item) the speed hit could be noticeable if you convert dates with 3dr party libraries or `Intl.DateTimeFormat`. Check the benchmark below and you'll see that manual formatting is instant.

All the solutions benchmarked:

```
` Chrome/122
--------------------------------------------------------------------
manual formatting              1.00x | x10000000 878 889 903 906 932
regexp                         9.94x |  x1000000 873 880 891 912 913
formatToParts and reduce      19.02x |   x100000 167 169 170 172 190
formatToParts and filter/map  20.39x |   x100000 179 186 186 187 193
--------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script>

    const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { year: "numeric", day: "2-digit", month: "short" });

    // @benchmark regexp
    formatter.format(new Date).replace(/[\s,]+/g, '/')

    // @benchmark formatToParts and reduce
    formatter.formatToParts(new Date).reduce((str, item) => item.type === 'literal' ? str : str += (str ? '/' : '') + item.value, '')

    // @benchmark formatToParts and filter/map
    formatter.formatToParts(new Date)
        .filter(item => item.type !== 'literal')
        .map(item => item.value)
        .join('/')

    // @benchmark manual formatting
    const formatMonth = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { month: 'short' }).format
    const months = [...Array(12).keys()].map(idx => formatMonth(new Date(2022, idx)))

    // @run
    const date = new Date;
    `${months[date.getMonth()]}/${date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${date.getFullYear()}`

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: The first one worked pretty well! Thanks!

Comment: @ErickaSanchez but i recommend to format dates manually. i've added the solution to the answer and also a benchmark of all solutions. as you can see the manual formatting is almost instant

Comment: @ErickaSanchez updated the answer with an important info and updated the benchmarks