# Localize date and time

Tags: javascript, date

I've made a function for user's last Visit Detection and I'm trying to convert the default date to my local date but when I add `toLocaleString()` method it gives me an error: `d.getFullYear is not a function`

```
var visitDetection = document.querySelectorAll('.visit-detection')[0];
        if(visitDetection){
            var neverVisited = document.querySelectorAll('.never-visited')[0];
            var beforeVisited = document.querySelectorAll('.before-visited')[0];
            var visitBeforeTime = document.querySelectorAll('.visit-before-time')[0];
            var lastVisitValue = localStorage.getItem(pwaName+'-Last-Visited');
            var options = { year: "numeric",day: "numeric", month: "long", };
            var d = new Date().toLocaleString("fa-IR", options);
            var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate();
            var strTime = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
            if(!lastVisitValue){
                neverVisited.style.display="block";
                beforeVisited.style.display="none";
                localStorage.setItem(pwaName+'-Last-Visited', 'آخرین بازدید شما ' + strDate +' در '+ strTime)
            } else {
                neverVisited.style.display="none"
                beforeVisited.style.display="block"
                visitBeforeTime.append(lastVisitValue)
                localStorage.setItem(pwaName+'-Last-Visited', 'آخرین بازدید شما ' + strDate +' در '+ strTime)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date().toLocaleString("fa-IR", options)` returns a string and a string doesn't have `getFullYear()` method and that throws the error. Basically you do a manual date formatting so you don't need `toLocaleString()` at all.

Considering your manual formatting it's not a bad choice, but you should avoid using `var` in modern JS plus you could use a template string to make your code here more readable and don't forget to pad numbers with `0` since the date methods here return numbers that could be variable string length.

Considering using `Date`'s `toLocaleString()`, `toLocaleDateString()`, `toLocaleTimeString()` I recommend to check my answer here: [Custom delimiter in a formatted date with Date::toLocaleDateString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442587/custom-delimiter-in-a-formatted-date-with-datetolocaledatestring/76442599#76442599)

```js
const d = new Date();
const pad = num => num.toString().padStart(2, '0');
const strDate = `آخرین بازدید شما ${d.getFullYear()}/${pad(d.getMonth() + 1)}/${pad(d.getDate())} در ${pad(d.getHours())}:${pad(d.getMinutes())}:${pad(d.getSeconds())}`;
console.log(strDate);
```

We can improve our formatting code to make it more elegant by using a tagged template:

```js
const d = new Date();

const formatDate = (strings, ...nums) => 
    nums.map((num, idx) => strings[idx] + num.toString().padStart(2, '0')).join('') + strings.at(-1);

const strDate = formatDate`آخرین بازدید شما ${d.getFullYear()}/${d.getMonth() + 1}/${d.getDate()} در ${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}:${d.getSeconds()}`;
console.log(strDate);
```

Comment: I tried both way but still same error